# Copy a repo clone in dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to clone a repository in my dockerfile and then copy that repository into a specific folder of the docker container.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM node:11-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./package.json /usr/src/app/

RUN apk --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add git python make g++ \
    && git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git:// \
    && apk add curl \
    && apk add git bash && git clone https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it.git \
    && yarn install \
    && yarn cache clean --force \
    && apk del build-dependencies 

COPY wait-for-it /usr/src/app
```

This outputs: `ERROR: Service 'exchanges_api' failed to build: COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder416734770/wait-for-it: no such file or directory`

However, if I add a `RUN ls` before the copy I get confirmation the file exists, any idea where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From this error '' no such file or directory" you see that is the problem with file path and indeed as you can see there is a mistake in this `COPY . /package. json` this is not a valid path you either need something like `.. /package.json` or simply `package.json` depends on where is the file located in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

`COPY` is used to copy resource from host machine to your docker image. But in you use case, it looks like you are trying to copy resource from one location to other **within** the docker image.

Replace `COPY wait-for-it /usr/src/app` with the following:

```
RUN cp -a wait-for-it /usr/src/app
```

Comment: nop, the file exists in that folder, but I want to persist it beyond the run command so that its saved in the actual docker container

Comment: Please share your project structure.

Comment: You'd use `COPY` if it existed in the same host directory as the `Dockerfile`.  The (filesystem) results of `RUN` commands are persisted in the image.